# Python For Loop (Iterating Variable Name = List Name)

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am running this Python code:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for numbers in numbers:
    print(numbers)
    for letters in letters:
       print(letters)
```

and got this output:

```
1
a
b
c
2
c
3
c
```

I do not understand why I got this output . What I am asking is what is the effect of using iterating variable with the same name with the sequence(list)?

Comment: Think of the loop as setting `letters = 'a'`, `letters = 'b'`, `letters = 'c'` the first time. The next time, it’s just looping over `'c'`.

Comment: `for letters in letters` is the culprit. change your loop variable name, specially in an inner loop (or reset `letters` inside the outer loop). Anyway, it should be `for letter in letters`.

Comment: Once you are done with the first iteration of the outer loop, i.e., when the inner loop has done a full cycle, `letters == 'c'`. So on the second iteration `for letters in letters:` you are iterating over the string `"c'`

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ on the contrary, I think OP is aware of the identical variable names: "(Iterating Variable Name = List Name)" quoting from title of the question.

Comment: I am aware of the similarity between the iterating variable name and the list name, I just do not understand why this weird behavior occurs.

Answer (score 5):

- why does it work the first time?

because `for letters in letters:` initialise the iteration on the name `letters` (which is a `list` of strings). Even if the `letter` variable is reassigned, the original list is already stored in the `for` iterator, so the loop runs properly

- why it doesn't work / works so weirdly the next times?

After the first iteration, the name `letters` is no longer referencing your start list, but is referencing the last element of the original list, AKA `c`. Since strings are *iterable*, you don't get an error (like you would have gotten if `letters` were a list of integers, for instance), it just yields `c` over and over.

note that `for letters in letters` in itself makes no sense. The list of letters is properly named `letters`, but the variable name should be named `letter`, for instance, else it makes the code unclear.